# Typeerror: Failed to execute fetch on window. Invalid name

Tags: javascript, twitter, graphql, request, fetch-api

I am trying to hit twitter's graphql api through the network tab(obviously on same origin)

Here's my current implementation:

```
// Example POST method implementation:
async function getData(username, data = {}) {
    let URL = `https://api.twitter.com/graphql/k5XapwcSikNsEsILW5FvgA/UserByScreenName?variables={"screen_name":"${username}","withSafetyModeUserFields":true}&features={"hidden_profile_likes_enabled":true,"hidden_profile_subscriptions_enabled":true,"responsive_web_graphql_exclude_directive_enabled":true,"verified_phone_label_enabled":true,"subscriptions_verification_info_is_identity_verified_enabled":true,"subscriptions_verification_info_verified_since_enabled":true,"highlights_tweets_tab_ui_enabled":true,"responsive_web_twitter_article_notes_tab_enabled":true,"creator_subscriptions_tweet_preview_api_enabled":true,"responsive_web_graphql_skip_user_profile_image_extensions_enabled":false,"responsive_web_graphql_timeline_navigation_enabled":true}&fieldToggles={"withAuxiliaryUserLabels":false}`
    // Default options are marked with *
    const response = await fetch(URL, {
        method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            ":path": `/graphql/k5XapwcSikNsEsILW5FvgA/UserByScreenName?variables={"screen_name":"${username}","withSafetyModeUserFields":true}&features={"hidden_profile_likes_enabled":true,"hidden_profile_subscriptions_enabled":true,"responsive_web_graphql_exclude_directive_enabled":true,"verified_phone_label_enabled":true,"subscriptions_verification_info_is_identity_verified_enabled":true,"subscriptions_verification_info_verified_since_enabled":true,"highlights_tweets_tab_ui_enabled":true,"responsive_web_twitter_article_notes_tab_enabled":true,"creator_subscriptions_tweet_preview_api_enabled":true,"responsive_web_graphql_skip_user_profile_image_extensions_enabled":false,"responsive_web_graphql_timeline_navigation_enabled":true}&fieldToggles={"withAuxiliaryUserLabels":false}

`,
            ":authority": "api.twitter.com",
            ":method": "GET",
            ":scheme": "https",
            "Authorization": "Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA",
            "Cookie": `guest_id_marketing=v1:170955125343839663; guest_id_ads=v1:170955125343839663; guest_id=v1:170955125343839663; gt=1764611971050074353; _ga=GA1.2.251089784.1709551255; _gid=GA1.2.393957230.1709551255; personalization_id="v1_5jbQDTm8Tn2sQ/f9diPocA=="
`,
            "Origin": "https://twitter.com",
            "Referer": "https://twitter.com",
            "X-Client-Transaction-Id": "I7fMTBcu/4HmKfngKEMY6kPjahaJoBRzqcr/bTYgBPINSk5CBpY1sDLiD3RBiJlAp0RotSI7wGYBtp0x28iZw/JR986wIg",
            "X-Guest-Token": "1764611971050074353"

        },
        redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
        referrerPolicy: "strict-origin-when-cross-origin", // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url

    });
    return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

getData("sama").then((data) => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
});
```

All this is being done on a public profile page such as https://twitter.com/sama

Its giving me this error

```
Promise {<rejected>: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Invalid name
```

I didn't copy all the headers just the ones I thought were important

And I decoded the urls and cookie strings from the network tab(so no wrong chars in the request probably)

What am I doing wrong here?

Also all of the tokens etc are safe to be public as it was all on an unlogged incognito window!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing colons from parameter names:

```js
    headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "path": `/graphql/k5XapwcSikNsEsILW5FvgA/UserByScreenName?variables={"screen_name":"${username}","withSafetyModeUserFields":true}&features={"hidden_profile_likes_enabled":true,"hidden_profile_subscriptions_enabled":true,"responsive_web_graphql_exclude_directive_enabled":true,"verified_phone_label_enabled":true,"subscriptions_verification_info_is_identity_verified_enabled":true,"subscriptions_verification_info_verified_since_enabled":true,"highlights_tweets_tab_ui_enabled":true,"responsive_web_twitter_article_notes_tab_enabled":true,"creator_subscriptions_tweet_preview_api_enabled":true,"responsive_web_graphql_skip_user_profile_image_extensions_enabled":false,"responsive_web_graphql_timeline_navigation_enabled":true}&fieldToggles={"withAuxiliaryUserLabels":false}

`,
            "authority": "api.twitter.com",
            "method": "GET",
            "scheme": "https",
            "Authorization": "Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA",
            "Cookie": `guest_id_marketing=v1:170955125343839663; guest_id_ads=v1:170955125343839663; guest_id=v1:170955125343839663; gt=1764611971050074353; _ga=GA1.2.251089784.1709551255; _gid=GA1.2.393957230.1709551255; personalization_id="v1_5jbQDTm8Tn2sQ/f9diPocA=="
`,
            "Origin": "https://twitter.com",
            "Referer": "https://twitter.com",
            "X-Client-Transaction-Id": "I7fMTBcu/4HmKfngKEMY6kPjahaJoBRzqcr/bTYgBPINSk5CBpY1sDLiD3RBiJlAp0RotSI7wGYBtp0x28iZw/JR986wIg",
            "X-Guest-Token": "1764611971050074353"

        },
```

Comment: Hey this is right in the context of my question but twitter's still rejecting my request(probably because of bad headers etc). I am getting this "TypeError: Failed to fetch\n    at getData (<anonymous>:5:28)\n    at <anonymous>:34:1" Can you help me figure out a complete way to make a 200 request?